# Data Binding on another page does not work

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I can bind a data in MainPage.xaml but I can't bind on another pages. I have a Model named "Document" in this project.

Example:
I've bind `FileName` in MainPage

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="NameOfFile" Text="{Binding Document.FilePath}"/>
```

Text shows FileName when I open a file.

But FileName is not shown on Another Page.

```xml
<TextBlock x:Name="NameOfFile1" Text="{Binding Document.FilePath}"/>
```

I want to show FileName on another page. How can I do that?

Comment: How did you set the `DataContext` of your pages? What is `Document`? Your question doesn't tell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two ways.

#### The first one directly passes the value to the new page.

**In MainPage**

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      Frame rootFrame = new Frame();

      Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

      rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1),document);    
 }
```

**In Another Page.**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var param = (Document)e.Parameter; 
    Document.FilePath= param.FilePath;
}
```

#### The second way is to use **singleton** model for Document.

**DocumentViewModel.cs**

```
public sealed class Document : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly Document instance = new Document("default path");

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string filePath;
    public int fileSize;

    static Document() { }
    private Document(string value) 
    {
        this.filePath = value;
    }
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return filePath; }
        set
        {
            filePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public static Document Instance { get { return instance; } }
   
}
```

**MainPage**

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind document.FilePath,Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
```

---

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    Document document = Document.Instance;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
            
        document.FilePath = "hello world!";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = new Frame();
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
        // document.FilePath = "hello world! hello world! hello world!";
    }
}
```

**BlankPage1**

```
<TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind document.FilePath, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
```

---

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
{
    Document document = Document.Instance;

    public BlankPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
           
    }
}
```